# c++ Possible null pointer dereference

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference, cppcheck

I ran cppcheck over some code to look for possible runtime errors. And it is reporting a possible null pointer dereference with the following situation:

```
Foo* x = ... //defined somewhere

...

Foo* y(x); //possible null pointer dereference.
```

Edit: Better example

```
for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    Foo* x( ArrayOfObjsContainingFooPtr[i].FooPtr ); // line 3
    if( !x )                                         // line 4
        continue;
}
```

Error message from cppcheck:

> [C:\file.cpp:3]: (error) Possible null
>   pointer dereference: x - otherwise it
>   is redundant to check if x is null at
>   line 4

But I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: Can you post a more complete example? I suspect there is a code path that leads to this situation. Note that static code analysis tools are not perfect and this might be a false positive.

Comment: Neither of those examples dereference x.

Comment: your examples are still not complete. Can you post minimal compilable code? The code above CAN cause null pointer dereferencing.

Answer (score 3):

I am really surprised that you got that warning. For me, it works exactly the opposite. Using cppcheck 1.46.1 compiled from sources in Linux. This is fine:

```
struct Foo {
  int x;
};

struct Obj {
  Foo *FooPtr;
};

#define N 10

static Obj ArrayOfObjsContainingFooPtr[N];

int main() {
  for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    Foo* x( ArrayOfObjsContainingFooPtr[i].FooPtr ); // line 3
    if( !x )                                         // line 4
      continue;
  }
}
```

Now, with *this* loop body it is also "fine" according to cppcheck although it segfaults if I actually try to run it, obviously:

```
Foo* x( ArrayOfObjsContainingFooPtr[i].FooPtr ); // line 3
if (x->x == 0)
  break;
if( !x )                                         // line 4
  continue;
```

Even this is "fine":

```
int main() {
  Foo *p = 0;
  if (p->x == 0)
    return 1;
```

And this finally generates "possible" null pointer dereference. Possible, right:

```
int main() {
  Foo *p = 0;
  p->x = 0;
```

The funny thing is that this, while being completely equivalent to an earlier example, gives definite (not "possible") null pointer dereference:

```
int main() {
  Foo *p = 0;
  if ((*p).x == 0)
    return 1;
```

The conclusion: cppcheck is a really buggy tool.

Comment: +1: for demonstrating the numerous faults in this tool that are highly relevant to the question and apparently not very hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

Take the following:

```
Foo* x = ptr_foo; //ptr_foo is defined earlier in the code.
```

But what if `ptr_foo` was written to at another point in the program, in another file?  For example, let's say that in `someotherfile.c` you find:

```
ptr_null = 0;
```

Then it is entirely possible that `Foo* x = ptr_foo;` could cause bad mojo, when `y(x)` is called, if `y` dereferences `x`.

From my experience, static analysis tools tend to report a large number of false positives, because they do not have any state information about the program.

If you **really** want to make sure you won't run into a null pointer reference, you could try something like:

```
Foo* x = 0;
if(ptr_foo != 0){
    x = ptr_foo;
}else{
    x = //something else
}
```

Comment: Alternate (IMHO cleaner) version of your code sample: `Foo* x = ptr_foo ? ptr_foo : /* something else */;`

Comment: No, there is never any possibility that "Foo* x = ptr_foo; could be bad mojo". It's a pointer copy, not a dereference.

Comment: This is what I was thinking Andrew

Comment: @Andrew: if "Foo* x = ptr_foo; //where ptr_foo = 0", then calling "y(x) //assuming y dereferences x" will definitely be bad mojo.  I see that I did not communicate that in my answer, so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wrap up to the post from Sergey Tachenov:

```
 Foo* x( ArrayOfObjsContainingFooPtr[i].FooPtr ); // line 3
if (x->x == 0)
 break;
if( !x )                                         // line 4
 continue;
```

This one is now correctly detected by cppcheck:

```
 $ cppcheck --enable=all nullptrderef9.cpp 
 Checking nullptrderef9.cpp...
 [nullptrderef9.cpp:20] -> [nullptrderef9.cpp:22]: (warning) Possible null pointer dereference: x - otherwise it is redundant to check it against null.
```

Also the next example is detected correctly:

```
int main() {
  Foo *p = 0;
  if (p->x == 0)
  return 1;
}
```

Here is the output from cppcheck:

```
 $ cppcheck --enable=all nullptrderef10.cpp 
 Checking nullptrderef10.cpp...
 [nullptrderef10.cpp:19]: (error) Possible null pointer dereference: p
```

Even the next example demonstrates that Cppcheck works as expected:

```
 int main()
 {
    Foo *p = 0;
    if ((*p).x == 0)
       return 1;
 }
```

Here is the output:

```
$ cppcheck --enable=all nullptrderef11.cpp
  Checking nullptrderef11.cpp...
  [nullptrderef11.cpp:18]: (error) Possible null pointer dereference: p
  [nullptrderef11.cpp:18]: (error) Null pointer dereference
```