# Did I find a bug in CppCheck? Why do I get the "Null pointer dereference" error here?

Tags: c++, pointers, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I'm using Cppcheck to manage my code. I have the following function:

```
bool my_function(std::string my_string) const
{
 return 0 == my_string.compare("Some text");  // line 3
}
```

To my surprise, I get the *Null pointer dereference* in the line 3.

I am completely confused: there are no pointers in my function. Why do I get this error?

I've tried to investigate it:

1. I checked if the string *my_string* is empty.
2. I created an object using *"My text"* to make sure that Cppcheck doesn't complain about using a temporary object:

   ```
   bool my_function(std::string my_string) const
   { 
    std::string str("Some text");
    return 0 == my_string.compare(str);  // line 3
   }
   ```

What else can I do? Is is a bug in Cppcheck? Is there a problem with the *compare* function itself? I'd be surprised if this was the case, since cppcheck doesn't complain about any other *std* functions that are used in my project.

Note: I'm not asking about the *possible Null pointer dereference* error, so this is not a duplicate of any of the following questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312399/why-do-i-get-a-possible-null-pointer-dereference-warning), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474357/c-possible-null-pointer-dereference) or [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750481/cppcheck-possible-null-pointer-dereference).

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I see nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: did you try `return (0 == my_string.compare("Some text"));`? Just maybe

Comment: Just to be clear, the code works without crashing but its just that cppcheck is reporting error, right ?

Comment: @FirstStep, I just tried that and it works now, thanks! But why? The change you suggested shouldn't have any impact on the code. Does it?

Comment: @Arunmu, yes, that's right.

Comment: Eventually it does have an impact on the code. And I don't know why still, let me know when you know!

Comment: I would say it is a false positive for cppcheck. It is not really a bug since as in any static analysis tool false positive are always possible, even if *[cppcheck] goal is to detect only real errors in the code (i.e. have zero false positives)* (from cppcheck page). But you could signal it (with the parentheses workaround) to the cppcheck dev team...

Comment: What happens if you use `operator==` and do `return my_string == "Some text";`?

Comment: Try to break the statement on more lines and see in wich line the error lies (also the comparison). I have  a suspect

Comment: @FirstStep "Eventually it does have an impact" - which is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am a Cppcheck developer.

It looks like a bug in Cppcheck. However I fail to reproduce this false positive. If you don't use latest Cppcheck please update. Otherwise please report this in the cppcheck bug tracker: http://trac.cppcheck.net